# How to transfer my account from old phone to new phone

Tags: pokemon-go

I bought a new phone and want to know how to transfer my account from old phone to new phone without starting all over again?

Comment: you should be able to just sign in with your email on it.

Answer (score 2):

Just log in with your Google or Trainer Club account